# Refactoring nested loop with shared variables

Tags: python, loops, scope, nested, refactoring

I have a function that process some quite nested data, using nested loops. Its simplified structure is something like this:

```
def process_elements(root):
    for a in root.elements:
        if a.some_condition:
            continue
        for b in a.elements:
            if b.some_condition:
                continue
            for c in b.elements:
                if c.some_condition:
                    continue
                for d in c.elements:
                    if d.some_condition:
                        do_something_using_all(a, b, c, d)
```

This does not look very pythonic to me, so I want to refactor it. My idea was to break it in multiple functions, like:

```
def process_elements(root):
    for a in root.elements:
        if a.some_condition:
            continue
        process_a_elements(a)
        
def process_a_elements(a):
    for b in a.elements:
        if b.some_condition:
            continue
        process_b_elements(b)
        
def process_b_elements(b):
    for c in b.elements:
        if c.some_condition:
            continue
        process_c_elements(c)
        
def proccess_c_elements(c):
    for d in c.elements:
        if d.some_condition:
            do_something_using_all(a, b, c, d) # Problem: I do not have a nor b!
```

As you can see, for the more nested level, I need to do something using all its "parent" elements. The functions would have unique scopes, so I couldn't access those elements. Passing all the previous elements to each function (like `proccess_c_elements(c, a, b)`) does look ugly and not very pythonic to me either...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data/object you're trying to run this on?

Comment: The question is more about the concept than about the specific problem. The example is a very simplified version of it, the real data is a way more complicated. In fact, the "nested data" is a mix of Python objects, dicts and JSON arrays...

Comment: perhaps classes and inheritance? in case the ratio between a, b, c, d is appropriate to the inheritance concept

Comment: I think that is not feasible in this case.
First, because in reality a, b, c and d are not just objects, I just put it that way to make the example clearer. But in fact, they are a mix of objects and dicts. Also, all having the same attributes (`elements`, `some_condition`) is a simplification for the example too.
Second, because the data structure was not built by me. It comes from an external library out of my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I've found a solution, which is to encapsulate all the proccessing inside a class, and having attributes to track the currently processed elements:

```
class ElementsProcessor:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        
        self.currently_processed_a = None
        self.currently_processed_b = None
        
    def process_elements(self):
        for a in self.root.elements:
            if a.some_condition:
                continue
            self.process_a_elements(a)
            
    def process_a_elements(self, a):
        self.currently_processed_a = a
        for b in a.elements:
            if b.some_condition:
                continue
            self.process_b_elements(b)
            
    def process_b_elements(self, b):
        self.currently_processed_b = b
        for c in b.elements:
            if c.some_condition:
                continue
            self.process_c_elements(c)
    
    def process_c_elements(self, c):
        for d in c.elements:
            if d.some_condition:
                do_something_using_all(
                    self.currently_processed_a,
                    self.currently_processed_b,
                    c,
                    d
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact data structures and the complexity of your code but you may try to use a list to pass the object reference to the next daisy chained function something like the following:

```
def process_elements(root):
    for a in root.elements:
        if a.some_condition:
            continue
        listobjects=[]
        listobjects.append(a)
        process_a_elements(a,listobjects)
        
def process_a_elements(a,listobjects):
    for b in a.elements:
        if b.some_condition:
            continue
        listobjects.append(b)
        process_b_elements(b,listobjects)

def process_b_elements(b,listobjects):
    for c in b.elements:
        if c.some_condition:
            continue
        listobjects.append(c)
        process_c_elements(c,listobjects)
        
def process_c_elements(c,listobjects):
    for d in c.elements:
        if d.some_condition:
            listobjects.append(d)
            do_something_using_all(listobjects)

def do_something_using_all(listobjects):
    print(listobjects)
```

Comment: Hummm, this would not work for this case, as it would create a list with all `a`s, `b`s, `c`s and `d`s, and what I need to do is to do something with the a-b-c-d combinations.

Comment: No it won't add all a's b's and c's as it is only adding the ones that do not satisfy the "if" condition.

Comment: What I mean is that I need to use `do_something_using_all` with combinations of a-b-c-d. Not with a list of all `a`s, `b`s, `c`s and `d`s that satisfy the condition.

Comment: Understood, but in my solution a new instance of list "listobjects" is created for each iteration of root.elements which means each time do_something_using_all is called, it will only have one combination of a, b, c and d. "listobjects" is not an object with global scope.

Comment: Yes, but I do not need to call it one time per iteration of root. I might need to do it per combination of a-b-c-d. However, your suggestion has given me an idea... I am going to make some tests and see if it works...